# setFilter работает по-разному

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Почему вот так фильтр работает так, как нужно:

```
k4.setFilter('properties.types_object == "novostroyka" && properties.square < 100 && properties.square > 10');
```

А вот так нет:

```
k4.setFilter('properties.types_object == "novostroyka"');
k4.setFilter('properties.square < 100 && properties.square > 10');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setFilter() перезатирается, поэтому в вашем случае будет применен последний

Comment: понял, спасибо.

Comment: @АльбертАлександров, если ответ решил вашу проблему, то пометьте его как лучший.